# Efficient Key/Value table

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, database-design

I need a table for storing key/value pairs (like the Windows Registry).  Here is what I have:

```
CREATE TABLE REG         
(                       
    ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    DATA VARCHAR(1024),  
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)          
);
```

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, 2008, and 2005.

Can anyone offer a more efficient idea to storing key/value pairs.

I am storing keys like this:

/USER/REX/AUTO_LOGIN = "T"

/USER/REX/MESSAGE/1 = "This is a longer message"

At about 10000 records I am already seeing performance issues.

Comment: Performance issues where?  With the primary key set to ID, SQL Server should index that column and queries off it should still be very quick at 10k rows.  Assuming of course you are doing queries like: `SELECT * from reg WHERE id = '/USER/REX/AUTO_LOGIN'`.  If you start throwing in wildcards that can affect things...

Comment: I am using this query: SELECT DATA FROM REG WHERE ID=?

Comment: and this:  UPDATE REG SET DATA=? where KEY=?

Comment: @GenuineRex The simple equi-search you are doing should be incredibly fast on your database structure (I'm, assuming you meant ID, not KEY in your second comment about UPDATE). Your problem lies elsewhere. Are both SELECT **and** UPDATE slow? If only UPDATE, do you have any triggers?

Answer (score 2):

You could introduce an additional column which is a hash of the key name; e.g. "/USER/REX/AUTO_LOGIN" might hash to 102454.  You could then add an index on the hash column (or a composite index over the hash column and the key name column) and include it in the where clause of any queries; e.g

```
SELECT DATA
FROM REG
WHERE HASH = 102454 and ID = '/USER/REX/AUTO_LOGIN'
```

Searching on an `int` column should be far more efficient than querying the `varchar` `ID` column, and should have the effect of narrowing down to a few rows with the same hash value, which will then be inspected for matching `ID` values.

Comment: Sorry, but this sounds like a bad idea to me, for following reasons: (1) secondary indexes are expensive in a clustered table (you could make it non-clustered, but this has a price too). (2) you can't avoid index on ID anyway (since it's PK), so why not just use _it_? I'm not at all convinced that the non-composite index on hash will actually be faster in practice (it's more compact but there will be "false positives"). OTOH, composite on hash and ID makes no sense at all. Do you actually have a practical experience with this technique? Did you perform benchmarks on realistic amounts of data?

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using `varchar(255)` as my primary key, opting for a unique index instead:

```
CREATE TABLE REG (
    id bigint identity not null,
    key VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    DATA VARCHAR(1024),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);

create unique index reg_key on REG(key);
```

Comment: I thought about this but then I would need an index on key and any SELECT query would read down the index on key and then have to do a lookup based on the primary key.  This could make updates faster, however, once I had the PK in memory.

Comment: @GenuineRex I would give it a try anyway: using large values of varying length in a clustered PK index just does not seem right, although I may be wrong on that one.